# React Component State modified before setState called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have read and fully understand https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate

Problem is I am still hitting instance where state is being modified before I call `setState`. This is a learning activity so please do not suggest a library like immutablejs.

The game snake is what I am making. Currently using a `step` method to see frame-by-frame.

`render` does this (Grid just loops state to build a grid):

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Grid state={this.state}>
            <button onClick={ this.step }>Step Frame</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `step` method looks like:

```
step = () => this.setState(state => {return this.moveSnakeHandler(state)});
```

Which calls:

```
moveSnakeHandler = (prevState : AppState) => {//This returns to setState
    console.log(this.state.snake[0], this.state.snake[1]);
    //this shows state having x: 25, y: 15} {x: 25, y: 14}

    const snake = moveSnake(prevState.snake, prevState.direction);

    console.log(...this.state.snake);
    //this shows state having {x: 25, y: 15} why is state modified?

    return snake;
}
```

The actual moving of the snake (this is outside the component class):

```
const moveSnake = (prevSnake, direction) => {
    //store what the current head is to change direction and placement
    const head : {x: number, y: number} = prevSnake[0];

    //Tail is the full snake my pop/not below to grow
    const tail : Array<{x: number, y: number}> = prevSnake;
    switch (direction) {
        case "up":
            head.y -= 1;
            break;
        case "down":
            head.y += 1;
            break;
        case "left":
            head.x -= 1;
            break;
        case "right":
            head.x += 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //remove the last element of the new tail so I do not grow
    tail.pop();

    //toggle pop on isApple when ready

    //put the new head and tail together same size as before with everything shifted one!
    const snake = [head].concat(tail)

    //return the object that will be updated.
    return {snake:snake};
}
```

My question is why is state is being mutated before `setState` is called?

I am able to fix all of this in move snake with the below but it just seems unnecessary...

```
const head : {x: number, y: number} = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevSnake[0]));

const tail : Array<{x: number, y: number}> = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevSnake));
```

Comment: You're directly modifying the array contained in `this.state.snake`, so when you `console.log(...this.state.snake)` you see those changes reflected.

Comment: @rayhatfield thank you except I clearly do not see where that is happening. I think I get it from some of the other comments. As I said this is a learning piece. I come from the land of Java so some of the js/ts gotcha get me...

Comment: As you come from Java, try to think of React and JS as functional languages rather than object-oriented. In functional JS, you hardly ever want to change property values of an object. Rather, you should create a new object with the new values and return that.

Comment: @JMadelaine I honestly thought I was when I did `const tail : Array<{x: number, y: number}> = prevSnake;` but apparently this is where I am a bit confused. That must not.

Comment: Yes, so `prevSnake` is an array. An array is a reference type, so when you say `const tail = prevSnake`, the `tail` array is the **same** array as `prevSnake`. It doesn't create a copy. Just like in OOP, reference types do not get copied using the assignment operator.

Comment: @JMadelaine so even passing in the `snake` array in as a parameter would not be a copy? It still points back to the state object? Just making sure I see the full error in my thought process.

Comment: Yes that's right. Arrays and objects get passed by reference, so whenever you use `=` or pass something as a parameter, it refers to the same object or array. Strings, numbers, booleans, etc... get passed as values so they are copied every time you use `=` or pass as a parameter. To copy objects or arrays, use the spread syntax: `const newArray = [...existingArray]`, or for objects: `const newObject = { ...existingObject }`. That will create a copy. You can mutate the copy without effecting the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating state directly. I have moved the logic from `moveSnake` into the `moveSnakeHandler` function:

```
const moveSnakeHandler = (prevState) => {
    console.log(this.state.snake[0], this.state.snake[1])
    //this shows state having x: 25, y: 15} {x: 25, y: 14}

    // head is the object contained in state - do not mutate this
    const head = prevState.snake[0]

    // tail is the array saved in state - do not mutate this
    const tail = prevState.snake

    // here we mutate head - this is bad
    switch (direction) {
        case 'up':
            head.y -= 1
            break
        case 'down':
            head.y += 1
            break
        case 'left':
            head.x -= 1
            break
        case 'right':
            head.x += 1
            break
        default:
            break
    }

    // here we mutate tail - this is bad
    tail.pop()

    console.log(...this.state.snake)
    //this shows state having {x: 25, y: 15}
    // we mutated state, so that is why state is modified

    return { snake: [head].concat(tail) }
}
```

Now do you see the problem?

You should never mutate state, you should only ever call `setState`. Even though you are using the `setState` function:

```
step = () => this.setState(state => {return this.moveSnakeHandler(state)});
```

The value `state` that you are passing to `moveStateHandler` is an object, so you cannot modify its properties because that means you're modifying the state object.

Some things that you can do to prevent this:

- **Never use the assignment operator (`=`) when setting new state values**, for example, don't use `=` or `+=` or any combination of this operator to set state.
- **Never use array functions that mutate the current array**. This includes `pop`, `push`, `splice`, etc. You should use non-mutating functions such as `slice`, `concat`, `filter`, etc.

---

To solve the issue, you can do something like this:

```
const moveSnakeHandler = (prevState: AppState) => {
    const { snake, direction } = prevState

    const newSnakeHead = getNewHead(snake[0], direction)

    // We use slice which returns a new array instead of mutating the existing one
    // slice(0, -1) returns a new array without the last element
    // We create a new array with the new snake head
    const newSnake = [newSnakeHead, ...snake.slice(0, -1)]

    // Return a new object for the new state
    return { ...prevState, snake: newSnake }
}

const getNewHead = (head: { x: number; y: number }, direction: string) => {
    // We always return a new object, never mutate the existing head
    switch (direction) {
        case 'up':
            return { ...head, y: head.y - 1 }
        case 'down':
            return { ...head, y: head.y + 1 }
        case 'left':
            return { ...head, x: head.x - 1 }
        case 'right':
            return { ...head, x: head.x + 1 }
        default:
            return head
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not realize the shortcoming of pop. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your state is being updated before the `setState` call because you directly modify the `snake` object rather than creating a new version of it without direct manipulation. The manipulation happens in `moveSnake` in the `switch` and at `tail.pop()`.

As you point out, you can fix this by making a deep copy of the `snake` using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`, this is one approach. Another is to create a new `snake` using the spread operator (`...`) and the `.slice` array method.

For example:

```
const moveSnake = (prevSnake, direction) => {
    const prevHead : {x: number, y: number} = prevSnake[0];
    let newHead : {x: number, y: number};
    switch (direction) {
        case "up":
            newHead = {x: prevHead.x, y: prevHead.y - 1};
            break;
        case "down":
            newHead = {x: prevHead.x, y: prevHead.y + 1};
            break;
        case "left":
            newHead = {x: prevHead.x - 1, y: prevHead.y};
            break;
        case "right":
            newHead = {x: prevHead.x + 1, y: prevHead.y};
            break;
        default:
            newHead = {x: prevHead.x, y: prevHead.y}; // or newHead = {...prevHead};
    }

    // newTail is prevSnake without the last element so I do not grow
    const newTail = prevSnake.slice(0, -1);

    //put the new head and tail together same size as before with everything shifted one!
    const newSnake = [newHead].concat(newTail);

    //return the object that will be updated.
    return {snake: newSnake};
}
```

Comment: So is the idea to pass in the snake object because using prevState is a shallow copy hence I am inadvertently updating the state object?